# Avl tree- find first key missing from the tree after i

Tags: data-structures, computer-science

I have the above problem that I'm trying to solve. The Avl tree has also a size of substree for every node and I know the maximum. I need to find the next first number after `i` which isn't in the tree. I need to do it in `O(logn)` time.

I got to

`if i bigger/equal the maximum then return i+1`,

I tried to do the other cases to find the minimum after `i` that is in the tree and I know I can do it in `O(logn)` if the number I found is bigger than `i+1` `return i+1`.

Now I understand that if `i+1` is in the tree, I need to keep searching but I'm getting time complexity bigger than I need this way. 
Would greatly appreciate any guidance. I'm not looking for code, only an idea or guidance how to solve it in the time specified

Comment: anyone? will really appreciate the help

Comment: anyone? will really appreciate the help

Comment: I understand that you may not be a native English speaker (I'm not one either) but your question is quite hard to read, try to make it more readable. It may help to markdown formatting to differentiate mathematical notation from plain text.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem might be more in within the time complexity analysis than the actual algorithm.

We know that, if properly done, the time of a search in a well formed AVL tree of height `log[2](n)` will always be `log[2](n)`.  Searching for a missing item in this case is no different than searching for an existing item.

Let's say you have an AVL tree `A` and it includes `i` and `i+1`. Then we know that `i+1` must either be the parent node of `i` and `i` being the left child node, or that `i+1` is the right child node of `i`. So we can conclude:

`if i ^ i+1 in A => i+1(l)=i v i(r)=i+1`

So if you find `i` and its parent node is not `i+1` its right child node has to be `i+1`. You can extend this to `i=i+1` after finding `i+1` and keep checking for this condition. The cool thing here is there is only one place you need to look at for every value `i+n` after `i` if you keep track of the nodes you have traversed through.

If you go through `[i+7, i+4, i]` You immediately know that if `A` contains `i` it cannot contain `i+1`. This is due to `i+1 < i+4` but `i < i+1 < i+4`.

If you go through `[i-6, i-2, i]` You also immediately know that if `A` contains `i+1` it cannot contain `i+1`. This is due to `i-2 < i+1` but `i-2 < i < i+1`.

If you were to go through `[i+7, i+3, i+1, i]` you found `i`, `i+1` and since `i+3` is not `i+2` you know `i+2` has to be the right child node of `i+1` since it must not be a child of `i+3` since it is smaller, but `i+1` already took the left child position. So you check if `i+1`'s right child is `i+2`, you continue checking for `i+4` from `i+3` on, essentially using the algorithm:

```
define stack //use your favourite stack implementaion
let n = root node
let i = yourval
while n.val != i
     stack.push(n)
     if i > n.val
         n = n.right
     else //equivalent to "else if i < n.val" since loop condition ensures they are not equal
         n = n.left

while !stack.empty
    if stack.peek.right.val != queue.peek.val + 1
        //Implies parent holds value
        temp = stack.pop.val + 1
        if(temp != stack.peek.val) //If the parent does not hold the next value return it
            return temp;
    else //Right child holds value
         stack.push(queue.peek.right)
         i = stack.peek.val
return i+1 //if the stack is empty eventually return the next value
```

Due to how AVL trees are formed your stack will at most be `2*logn[2](n)` elements large (if `i` is a leaf on the LHS and the last value is a leaf on the RHS). So in total your search will take `log[2](n)` for the initial search for `i` and another `2*log[2](n)` combined that makes `3*log[2](n)`, which in Big Omicron is still `O(log[2](n))`.

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, think about how you'd solve this problem if you had the elements in an array rather than an AVL tree. How would you solve this problem in time O(log n) in an array by using a modified binary search?

Once you've worked out how to do that, see if you can adjust your solution to work in a binary search tree rather than an array. The intuition will be pretty similar, except that instead of looking at the middle of the overall range of elements at each point, you'll look at the root of the current subtree, which, while close to the middle, isn't always exactly at the middle.